# C# solution using SortedList

Tags: c#

How to transform my code using SortedList. This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace LibraryTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book obj1 = new Book();

            Console.Clear();
            Library.SearchingForABook();
            Library.AllBooks();
            Library.InformationForABook("Sunlight", "John Doe", "FreePublish", 2019, "978-954-65-5919-7\n");
            Library.InformationForABook("Moonrise", "Anthony Doe", "PaidPublish", 2016, "978-178-32-9960-7\n");
            Library.InformationForABook("Nightlight", "Ana Bell", "EcoPublish", 2014, "978-954-28-1483-2\n");
            obj1.Show();

            Console.WriteLine("Delete book");
            Console.WriteLine();
            DeleteABook();
            GC.Collect();
        }
        public static void DeleteABook()
        {
            Book obj2 = new Book();
        }
    }
    class Library
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Library(string n)
        {
            _name = n;
        }
        public static void SearchingForABook()
        {
            List<string> books = new List<string>();
            books.Add("Joe Martin");
            books.Add("Ned Doe");
            books.Add("Ana Parker");

            Console.Write("Author search: ");
            string _name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (_name == "Ana Bell")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Book available");
                Console.WriteLine();
                InformationForABook("=Nightlight", "Ana Bell", "EcoPublish", 2014, "978-954-28-1483-2\n");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (_name == "Мигел де Сервантес")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Book available");
                Console.WriteLine();
                InformationForABook("Sunlight", "John Doe", "FreePublish", 2019, "978-954-65-5919-7\n");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (_name == "Moonrise")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Книга в наличност");
                Console.WriteLine();
                InformationForABook("Moonrise", "Moonrise", "PaidPublish", 2016, "978-178-32-9960-7\n");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No books available from this author.");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        public static void InformationForABook(string title, string author,
        string publishers, int year, string number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: " + title);
            Console.WriteLine("Author: " + author);
            Console.WriteLine("Publisher: " + publishers);
            Console.WriteLine("Year: " + year);
            Console.WriteLine("ISBN number: " + number);
        }
        public static void AllBooks()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Books available:");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    class Book
    {
        private string _title;
        private string _author;
        private string _publishers;
        private int _year;
        private string number;
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author
        {
            get
            {
                return _author;
            }
            set
            {
                _author = value;
            }
        }
        public string Publishers { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public Book()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add new book:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Title: ");
            _title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Author: ");
            _author = Console.ReadLine();
            string author = _author;
            Console.Write("Publisher: ");
            _publishers = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Year: ");
            _year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("ISBN number: ");
            number = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: " + _title);
            Console.WriteLine("Author: " + _author);
            Console.WriteLine("Publisher: " + _publishers);
            Console.WriteLine("Year: " + _year);
            Console.WriteLine("ISBN number: " + number);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        ~Book()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Book {0} is deleted", _title);
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is basically the same but I need to use SortedList. I apologize for my bad English(this is not my native language). And yes it's part of my homework. I will gladly accept any help or tips!
Also, I want to know if there is a way to use Cyrillic for the titles, authors, and publisher of the books because when I tried to run the code using Cyrillic symbols the compiler gave me an error

Comment: What happens when you try using `SortedList`?

Comment: *I need to use SortedList* - need to use it how? You can swap your `List<string>` to a `SortedList<string, Book>` and provide strings that define the sort order, and Books that define the book referenced by the string.. but why would you do this?

Comment: Right now, take note: never call `GC.Collect();` - C# managing objects in memory isn't like some windows recycle bin that needs you to empty it (if that's what you're thinking with the collect call after deleting a book)... This call should never appear in your code

Comment: My task is to make a listed structure with books using SortedList. My teacher said my way of doing it looks very basic and she insist to use SortedList...

Comment: OK, so use it.. I don't see the point but I'm not giving you the grades

Comment: And if I don't use GC.Collect(); does it mean that it will automatically empty the memory after I delete a book ?

Comment: You can check fundamentals of GC manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals. Yes, it will automatically release memory after some amount of time.

Comment: From what I see from the task my teacher basically wants to make a collection of books and probably that's why she wants me to use SortedList. From what I read basically SortedList is used for the collection of value pairs that are sorted by the keys and are accessible by key and by index.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the assignment is to make a very primitive "database" that allows  the user to lookup information about books. There are a ton of issues with the example code

Lets start with the `Book`-class. First of all it has both fields and auto-properties with the same names (except for "Author"), this is super confusing. Next it reads from console in the constructor, this is also bad practice, and should be moved to a separate method. Third, the show method prints to console, this is not so bad, but a better design is to override `ToString` and let the caller decide where to print the result to. Fixing this leads to a somewhat more reasonable looking class:

```
    class Book
    {
        public string Title { get;  }
        public string Author { get;  }
        public string Publishers { get;  }
        public int Year { get;  }
        public string ISBN { get;  }
        public Book(string title, string author, string publishers, int year,
            string isbn)
        {
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
            Publishers = publishers;
            Year = year;
            ISBN = isbn;
        }
        public static Book ReadFromConsole()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add new book:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Title: ");
            var title = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Author: ");
            var author = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Publisher: ");
            var publisher = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Year: ");
            int year;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year)){}
            Console.Write("ISBN number: ");
            var isbn = Console.ReadLine();
            return new Book(title, author, publisher, year, isbn);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Title: " + Title);
            sb.AppendLine("Author: " + Author);
            sb.AppendLine("Publisher: " + Publishers);
            sb.AppendLine("Year: " + Year);
            sb.AppendLine("ISBN number: " + ISBN);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

To create a library you would presumably add some fixed set of books to some kind of collection that allows you a fast way to search by author. Using a hardcoded sequence of `if`-statements is not a good solution since it would require code changes for each book added. Even if books are hardcoded in the exercise, a good design would allow them to be serialized to a file instead.

A simple book search could look something like this:

```
            var myBooks = new List<Book>()
            {
                new Book("Sunlight", "John Doe", "FreePublish", 2019, "978-954-65-5919-7")
            };
            var myBookDictionary = myBooks.ToDictionary(b => b.Author, b => b);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Author");
            Book foundBook;
            while (!myBookDictionary.TryGetValue(Console.ReadLine(), out foundBook))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find author, try again");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(foundBook);
```

This shows a fairly straightforward example, but is is intentionally left incomplete. How would you go about listing all the books? Why did i use a dictionary instead of a sortedList? What is the difference between them? How would you accomplish case insensitive searching? How about searching for a partial name instead of an exact match?

I would highly recommend that you put in some work to study the documentation and other examples. And perhaps more significantly, think about how you should be building reusable components rather than just producing some predetermined output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips and the questions which you put. Now I have a better understanding of what I need to search and learn. My teacher just put the assignment and didn't give us any directions. That's more than enough help which really helps me to rework my code.